# Adding "End user agreement" gui to .deb package

Tags: dpkg

I am trying to build a .deb package for my application. I want my installer to prompt for "End user agreement (Accept or Decline)" GUI during installation through both terminal or Ubuntu software centre. I tried using zenity in the "preinst" script. It works fine for the terminal installation. But fails while installing through software centre. So please guide me with the right way of doing it.

Comment: See the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package for a working example of how it's done.

Comment: Reading `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package's source was really helpful but this dint solve my problem. The package had no end user agreement interface during installation. Anyway thanks :)